# Using modf with the same variable for both arguments?

Tags: c++, double, cmath, modulo

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/?kw=modf):

> `double modf  (double x     , double* intpart);`
>
> **Break into fractional and integral parts**
>
> Breaks x into an integral and a fractional part.
>
> The integer part is stored in the object pointed by intpart, and the
>   fractional part is returned by the function.
>
> Both parts have the same sign as x.

After this operation, I do not need the original value of x anymore. Is there any reason I cannot or should not use x for the second argument as well?

Example:

```
double pi = 3.14159
double pi_fraction = modf(pi, &pi);
// now pi_fraction = .14159 and pi = 3.0
```

There is nothing in the documentation I have found that explicitly forbids this but it does not explicitly allow it either.

Comment: "Is there anything preventing me from using x for the second argument as well?" No.

Comment: The first argument is passed-by-value (a copy), so there is no problem with what you are doing.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp of course (facepalm) thanks

Comment: Why somebody -1 this question? Whats wrong with you?